# Cannot write Variable from Class Module into textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a calendar(made of labels) in a frame, on a Userform. I run code for the click event on each label (representing a date on the calendar) from a sub in a class module. I take the value from the label and copy it to a textbox. This all seems to work, nothing errors, but the value does not copy.

I define the variables:

```
   Public Const iStartWeekday  As Integer = vbSunday
   Public iYear As Integer
   Public iMonth As Integer
   Public dtCalendar As Date
   Public DateLabels() As New clsDateLabels
   Public dtFirstOfMonth As Date
   Public dtLastOfMonth As Date
   Public iDay As Integer
   Public iWeekday As Integer
   Public dtWeekdayStart As Date
```

This is in the initialize event of the userform:

```
Public Sub MakeCal()
dtFirstOfMonth = DateSerial(iYear, iMonth, 1) dtLastOfMonth = DateSerial(iYear, iMonth + 1, 0) With Me
    .Caption = sFormName
    .sbMonth.Value = iMonth
    .sbYear.Value = iYear
    On Error GoTo 0
    For iDay = 1 To 42
        With .Controls("lblDay" & iDay)
            If WorksheetFunction.Weekday(dtFirstOfMonth, iStartWeekday) - iDay >= 1 Or Day(dtLastOfMonth) < WorksheetFunction.Sum(iDay - WorksheetFunction.Weekday(dtFirstOfMonth, iStartWeekday)) + 1 Then
                .Visible = False
            Else
                .Visible = True
                .Caption = WorksheetFunction.Sum(iDay - WorksheetFunction.Weekday(dtFirstOfMonth, iStartWeekday)) + 1
                If iDay = Day(Now) + WorksheetFunction.Weekday(dtFirstOfMonth, iStartWeekday) - 1 And iYear
= Year(Date) And iMonth = Month(Date) Then
                    .BackColor = RGB(205, 231, 247)
                Else
                    .BackColor = vbWhite
                End If
            End If
        End With
        ReDim Preserve DateLabels(1 To iDay)
        Set DateLabels(iDay).DateLabels = .Controls("lblDay" & iDay)
    Next iDay
    .lblMonthandYear.Caption = Format(DateSerial(iYear, iMonth, 1), "mmm yyyy")
    dtWeekdayStart = #1/1/2001#
    For iWeekday = 1 To 7
        If iStartWeekday = vbSunday Then
            .Controls("lblWeekday" & iWeekday).Caption = Left(Format(dtWeekdayStart + iWeekday - 2, "ddd"), 2)
        Else
            .Controls("lblWeekday" & iWeekday).Caption = Left(Format(dtWeekdayStart + iWeekday - 1, "ddd"), 2)
        End If
    Next iWeekday
```

End With
End Sub

Here is the sub on the class module:

```
    Option Explicit

    Public WithEvents DateLabels As MSForms.Label
    Public WithEvents DateStart As MSForms.ComboBox
    Public MyForm As String

Public Sub DateLabels_Click()
    dtCalendar = DateSerial(iYear, iMonth, DateLabels.Caption)
    EntryEdit.Controls(MyDateBox).Value = dtCalendar
    EntryEdit.FrameCal.Visible = False
End Sub
```

What's weird is that it all seems to work fine, but the value does not get copied to the Textbox. It even works if I copy the calendar out onto its own form. Is there something obvious I'm missing that would explain why the value does not copy?

Comment: **Q:** The sub in the class module: Is `EntryEdit` the userform which holds the `DateLabels` label? What is `FrameCal`?

Comment: Yes, EntryEdit is the userform. FrameCal is the frame with the calendar on it. The calendar is made of DateLabels that the class module sees.

Comment: And you've checked that `dtCalendar` has the expected value **after** assigning it the `DateSerial` value and **before** you've assigned it to the `MyDateBox`? Either with a breakpoint or debug statement?

Comment: Yes, correct. dtCalendar holds the value. Writing to MyDateBox (a textbox) does not error.

Comment: Do you have any event code for when the value in `MyDateBox` changes? Also, I think the textbox may need to be visible for the change to take effect.

Comment: There is no change event for MyDateBox. The textbox is visible. We don't seem to be getting any warmer!

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it affect anything if you change the `FrameCal.Visible = False` **before** setting the `MyDateBox.Value = dtCalendar`?